# How to access scala project file from project module

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have created a project `foo_proj` with Intellij (using SBT template) and added a module `test_mod` to it. The abbreviated directory looks like this

```
foo_proj
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── scala-2.11
│           └── proj_obj.scala
└── test_mod
    └── src
        └── tmod.scala
```

The contents of proj_obj.scala are:

```
package com.base.proj

object proj_obj {

}
```

If would like to be able to import this object (`proj_obj`) into the module file `tmod.scala`, but when I try `import com.base.proj`, it can't find it.

I am new to Scala, so if I want to use stuff from the project `src` directory in other project modules, how else should I be structuring things? Or is this an Intellij IDEA configuration that I need to set?

**Edit**

The contents of the generated build.sbt are

```
name := "test_proj"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

Comment: *1*- the default scala source dir name is `scala` not `scala-2.11`.
*2*- post your `build.sbt` file, so we can see your build configuration.
*3*- default test sources are found in `src/test/scala`, and not in `test_mod/src`
*4*- if you want a multi-project, check [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html)

Comment: @giladhoch Thanks. I edited the question for the build.sbt, though it was generated by Intellij. Intellij put both scala and scala-2.11 in src, but when I created the new class, it put the file in scala-2.11. Not sure if this is a bug or what. `test_mod/src` is my attempt to test module imports, not to create test sources (the test dir is as you describe). I'll look into multiple projects, though I was under the impression single projects could be broken up into modules in Scala. Again, thanks for the advice.

Comment: _just to clarify: a multiproject **is** a single project with submodules._ I would suggest not to create a project with intelliJ, but create the project manually. a bare minimum would be to create the `build.sbt` file, I usally create the dir structure as well. then, you can just import it in intelliJ. it's much safer that way. also, I suggest to add a `project/build.properties` file, and specify the sbt version explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to enable "submodules" (aka multiproject), all you need to do is add the following to your `build.sbt` file (or use a scala file under `project` dir):

```
lazy val root = project in file(".")

lazy val testModule = project in file("test_mod") dependsOn(root)
```

also, you should change `test_mod` dir structure.
either drop the `src` dir and put all your sources under the `test_mod` dir,
or use the sbt convention: `src/main/scala` or `src/test/scala`.